# Inserting an element at given position in list

Tags: list, scheme, cons

I don't know how I can append an element in n position in a list.
For example:

```
(insert-at new k lis)
(insert-at ’N 2 ’(a b c d e f))
=>
’(a b N c d e f)
```

It is ok?:

```
(define (insert-at new k lis)
  (cond (( null? lis)
         (list new))   
        (zero? k   
         (cons new lis))   
        (else       
         (cons (car lis)
               (insert-at new (- k 1) (cdr lis))))))
```

Comment: yes, after you put parens around the `zero? k` condition, like you have around `null? lis`. maybe add the check for `(zero? k)` under `(null? lis)` to handle it differently if it isn't zero (i.e., report an error or something).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll give you some hints - because this looks like homework, I can't give you a straight answer, and it'll be much more useful if you arrive at the solution by your own means. Fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (insert-at new k lis)
  (cond (<???>       ; if the list is empty
         <???>)      ; return a list with the single element `new`
        (<???>       ; if `k` is zero
         <???>)      ; cons `new` with the list
        (else        ; otherwise
         (cons <???> ; cons the lists' current element and
               (insert-at new <???> <???>))))) ; advance the recursion
```

Notice that here, "advancing the recursion" means passing the rest of the list and decrementing the `k` index by one unit. We're done once the `k` index is zero or the list's end is reached. Don't forget to test the procedure:

```
(insert-at 'N 2 '(a b c d e f))
=> '(a b N c d e f)

(insert-at 'N 0 '(a b c))
=> '(N a b c)

(insert-at 'N 3 '(a b c))
=> '(a b c N)
```

Comment: thank you the help men im a rookie in this type of programming language:       (define (insert-at new k lis)
  (cond (if (null? lis)
            '(new))      
        (zero? k      
               (cons new lis))
        (else        
         (cons (car l)
               (insert-at new (cdr l) (- n 1))))))

Comment: You almost got it! In the recursive call, you're sending the parameters in the wrong order, correct this. Remove that `if`, that's not right - simply use the `cond` for the conditions, no need for an `if`. And finally, the correct way to return a one-element list is this: `(list new)` , this won't work: `'(new)`

Comment: > (define (insert-at new k lis)   
  (cond (null?
         (list new))   
        (zero? k   
         (cons new lis))   
        (else       
         (cons (car l)
               (insert-at new (- n 1) (cdr l))))))
> 
(insert-at 4 3 '(1 2 3 5 6 7 8))
(4)
>

Comment: @NUTIC lots and lots of parenthesis problems. Please first _do_ take a [look](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._cond%29%29) at how to use the `cond` instruction, or alternatively, use a series of nested `if`s. Test it with the examples in my answer

Answer (score 2):

If you had two functions:

1. take-n - which returns as a list the first N elements, and
2. last-n - which returns as a list the last N elements

then you could write:

```
(define (insert-at value index list)
  (let ((len (length list)))
    (assert (<= 0 index len))
    (append (take-n index list)
            (list value)
            (last-n (- len index) list))))
```

Answer (score 1):

(DEFUN INS-ELEM (Nth item list)

(COND

((< Nth 1) (ERROR "Index too small ~A" Nth))

((= Nth 1) (CONS item list))

((ENDP list) (ERROR "Index too big"))

(T (CONS (FIRST list) (INS-ELEM (1- Nth) item(REST list))))))

Then, just call (INS-ELEM 2 'A '(B C D E F)) and view the result for yourself.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**#lang racket**

```
(define (insert-at Index item lst)

(cond

[(< Index 1) (error "Index too small: " Index)]

[(= Index 1) (cons item lst)]

[(> Index (length lst)) (error "Index too big: " Index)]

[else (cons (first lst) (insert-at (- Index 1) item (rest lst)))]))
```

## user3660248

Your idea of how to solve this problem seems right and makes sense, but your implementation of it in Racket was not right and I fixed it and now it works :)

Comment: calling `length` repeatedly is an anti-pattern. calling `length` at all in a list-handling function is usually a code smell (and here it is so, too).